# AlamofireObjectMapper in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I want to use AlamofireObjectMapper for the first time  to parse a json response in swift.

The response is :

```
{
    "city": {
        "total": 19,
        "data": [
            {
                "business_model": 2,
                "type": "Hotel"
            },
            {
                "business_model": 2,
                "type": "Hotel"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I mapped it like this :

```
class CityResponse: Mappable {

    var location: String?
    var data: [Data]?

    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        data <- map["city.data"]

    }
}

class Data: Mappable {

    var business_model: String?
    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        business_model <- map["business_model"]
    }
}
```

And in my controller:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "MY_URL").responseArray { (response: Response<[Data], NSError>) in

    print("res: \(response)")

    let forecastArray = response.result.value

    if let forecastArray = forecastArray {
        for forecast in forecastArray {
            print("model is : \(forecast.business_model)" )
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me error mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point out the path of your array:
**responseArray("data")**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "MY_URL").responseArray("data") { (response: Response<[Data], NSError>) in

    print("res: \(response)")

    let forecastArray = response.result.value

    if let forecastArray = forecastArray {
        for forecast in forecastArray {
            print("model is : \(forecast.business_model)" )
        }
    }
}
```